# C# Console always keep progress bar on the bottom

Tags: c#, console, cursor, progress-bar

What I am doing is reading logfile records into console. 
I want to keep a progressbar in the bottom and shows progress.

Problem is: the updating record will override the progressbar.

```
        private static void DrawProgressBar(int complete, int maxVal, int barSize, char progressCharacter)
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        int left = Console.CursorLeft;
        //int top = Console.CursorTop;

        //Console.CursorTop = Console.WindowTop + Console.WindowHeight - 1;

        decimal perc = (decimal)complete / (decimal)maxVal;
        int chars = (int)Math.Floor(perc / ((decimal)1 / (decimal)barSize));
        string p1 = String.Empty, p2 = String.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < chars; i++) p1 += progressCharacter;
        for (int i = 0; i < barSize - chars; i++) p2 += progressCharacter;

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write(p1);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        Console.Write(p2);

        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write(" {0}%", (perc * 100).ToString("N2"));
        Console.CursorLeft = left;
        //Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/How-to-ask) as there is no question here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cursor to the correct position.

Here is a simple example of SetCursorPosition:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.Write("i = {0}", i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Before you print the progressbar you need to find out where to start and resetting the cursor before writing the progressbar.

Comment: Thx for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do this and several very difficult ways to do this.

The easy way is to re-display the progress bar after every call to `Console.WriteLine`. That way it doesn't matter if a scrolled line overwrites the progress bar, because you're just going to re-display it.

If you want to get fancy, you need to handle scrolling yourself. That means creating a [TextWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) descendant that sees you writing to the last line (where the status line is), and , so that whenever some code wants to write to the bottom line where the progress bar is, you scroll the rest of the screen and write the new line in the vacated spot.

There are several problems with the second approach, the first being that in order to handle your own scrolling you have to call the Windows API; there is no support in the .NET BCL for manipulating the console screen buffer. I have code you can use to do it (see http://mischel.com/toolutil/consoledotnet.zip), but it's kind of involved. Plus, you have additional problems if the line you're writing is wider than the current window width. If the line wraps, then it'll overwrite your progress bar.

It really is simpler to just re-draw the status bar after every line, or perhaps group of lines if you're writing multiple lines at a time.

Comment: Thx, jim. I did it with the simpler way. :) At least the effect is okay.